# How can I read read program counter register in python using T32_ReadRegisterByName function

Tags: python, trace32

I am trying to read out the PC register from Trace32 debugger using python with T32_ReadRegisterByName() function, but as a return_code I always get 4112, instead of 0.

According to manual, if return_ code >0 means access error (e.g.wrong register name), but I do not know what kind of access error can cause this problem.

The way how I try to read out:

```
 name = "PC" 
 value = ctypes.c_uint32(-1)
 hvalue = ctypes.c_uint32(-1)

 return_code = T32_ReadRegisterByName(name, ctypes.byref(value), ctypes.byref(hvalue))
```

Maybe some command required before I try to read out the register? (Connection, set breakpoints working well)

Comment: Hello Bazsi91, have you solved the issue? If not try ```name = b"PC"```.

Comment: yes, thank you , that was the problem, "PC" was string type and needed to convert :)